# Puzzle about the animals

Tags: riddle, animals

> My four parts to lap the clay 
>   My four parts are sugarcoated 
>   My two parts looking stars 
>   My two parts are the high minaret 
>  
>   and my one innocent part kill ky bees

**Tell me who I am**

Comment: Did my answer help you to find your answer?

Comment: no, your answers were wrong

Comment: Does this require specific knowledge?  Seems like it might contain trivia regarding animals in a specific local (ky = Kentucky?)?  If so, maybe add a knowledge tag.

Answer (score 10):

My four parts to lap the clay

> Four feets of  a 4 leg animal, which always lap to the clay

My four parts are sugarcoated

> Many animals(like giraffe or cow etc) have 4 stomachs(rumen, reticulum, omasum and abomasum)

My two parts looking stars

> two eyes always looking around at hieght

My two parts are the high minaret

> two horns

and my one innocent part kill ky bees

> Tail to brush away or kill the bees

Tell me who I am

> I think you are giraffe

Hope this is near to your answer.